# input type=file issue of clicking on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the default behavior of HTML file control?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp

Clicking on the textbox of the filecontrol (left of "Choose file" button) opens up windows explorer to select file. Can I change this behavior and instead only open file on click of "Choose File" button?

Comment: No. Also do not use w3schools.com, it is known for spreading inaccuracies, misleding information and outright falsehoods.

Comment: Here's a more detailed explanation of why w3schools is bad http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to accomplish this rather strange behaviour, but take a look at section called [Using hidden file input elements using the click() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click%28%29_method), I think that's your best option at this point. You can create a button to synthetically trigger the `click` event on the actual box.